# datatables order by number doc and year of doc

Tags: datatables

I don't know how to implement a simple way to sort a column that show me number of doc with trailing year like:

```
COL 1    COL 2     COL 3    DOC. NR
------------------------------------
  x        x          x       2/2020
------------------------------------
  x        x          x       3/2020
------------------------------------
  x        x          x       4/2021
------------------------------------
  x        x          x       1/2022
------------------------------------
```

In my example i'd like to sort `doc. nr` col by asc or desc, based on number of doc (grouped by year).

I tried to set data-order with formula: `numberdoc + year` but it doesn't work cause, for example, 3 + 2020 is equal to 1 + 2022.... so this way is not correct. Any idea?

```
<td data-order="2020">1/2019</td>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
     "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    "columnDefs": [
            {
                targets: [1],
                data: {
                    _: "1.display",
                    sort: "1.@data-order",
                    type: "1.@data-order"
                }
            }
        ]
  });
} );
```

My fiddle: http://live.datatables.net/jivekefo/1/edit

Expected (ASC) result:

```
1/2018
2/2018
3/2018
1/2019
2/2019
3/2019
4/2019
1/2020
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved with this rule:

```
<td data-order="<?php echo (new Datetime($dateDoc))->format("Y") . str_pad(ltrim($numberDoc, "0"), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); /* example. 201900001 */ ?>">
```

http://live.datatables.net/jivekefo/2/edit